# asp.net Update Panel capturing Button clicks

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a page that has an ASP.NET UpdatePanel on it. The UpdatePanel contains a repeater, and within the repeater is a command button. (please see the code example below)

When I click on the button the first time, nothing happens. But the second time I click on the same button, then I get the event I was expecting triggered. I am at a loss as to why this is, though I am sure there is a simple explanation. Any advice would be helpful.

```
<!-- Drivers Table -->
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="DriverUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                        <ContentTemplate>    
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="DriverErrors" />
                            <asp:Repeater ID="DriverRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="DriverRepeater_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="DriverRepeater_ItemCommand">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <table cellspacing="0" class="section-table">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="bg_mid" colspan="7"><img src="/images/sections/drivers.png" alt="Drivers" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text_1 left-cell">#</td>
                                            <td class="text_1">Name</td>
                                            <td class="text_1">Date Of Birth</td>
                                            <td class="text_1">Gender</td>
                                            <td class="text_1">License #</td>
                                            <td class="text_1">Relationship</td>
                                            <td class="text_1" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                        <tr id="DriverRow" runat="server">
                                            <td class="text_2 required left-cell"><asp:Label ID="DriverNumber" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DriverNumber")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                                            <td class="text_2 required"><asp:Label ID="DriverName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                                            <td class="text_2 required"><asp:Label ID="BirthDate" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BirthDate")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                                            <td class="text_2 required"><asp:Label ID="Gender" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Gender").ToString() == "F" ? "Female" : "Male" %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                            <td class="text_2 required"><asp:Label ID="DriversLicenseNumber" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseInformation.DriversLicenseNumber")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                                            <td class="text_2 required"><asp:Label ID="RelationshipToApplicant" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RelationshipToApplicant")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                                            <td class="text_2 right-cell" align="right"><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="DriverEditButton" 
                                                ImageUrl="/images/edit.jpg" AlternateText="Edit" CommandName="Edit" CausesValidation="false" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </table>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Another thing I just noticed. Its the second click after rendering. So if I call update on the panel at any point, it takes two clicks again to trigger the event.

Comment: If you change the updatemode to Always does that always raise the events that you are expecting? Are there other UpdatePanels on the page?

Comment: I tried changing it to Always, but that actually throws errors with the calls on hte backend to Update() the panel. THere are multiple update panels on the page.

Answer (score 0):

make `UpdatePanel Mode="Conditional"` and `enableviewstate="true"` 
you not need to defined trigger and you work is done without it.

Comment: Nope, didn't help in this instance